# Read only in MySQL Workbench, even though there is a primary key

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench

I wrote this code which is intended to reorder my raw data as below,

```
SELECT Place_id,
MAX(case when days= 'Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;' then hours end) As 'Mon-Fri',
  MAX(case when days= 'Sat;' then hours end) As 'Sat',
  MAX(case when days= 'Sun;' then hours end) As 'Sun'

FROM CRdata.time   
GROUP BY Place_id
```

and when I ran the code on MySQL Workbench,

[the result gird shows read only which prevent me from importing the raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbzCW.png)

I have checked that the Place_id is set to be primary key but it is still read only.
I have searched for the solution but unfortunately cannot find any.
What can I do to may the table editable?

Comment: I do not follow you, import what data from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have aggregates in your query (MAX()) which cannot be used if you want the result set to be editable. Only plain selects, no union, no aggregates, with a primary key, no joins or subselects are allowed.